# How to guess when Chrome beta APIs will become stable

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-os

I would like to know when Chrome's declarative web request API will be in the stable channel (https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declarativeWebRequest).  I realize that is asking a lot.  I'd like to write an extension that depends on a beta API though and am just curious if there is a best approach for guessing when it might become stable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

declarativeWebRequest is not currently scheduled for promotion to stable. There were some issues with certain use cases that made the current design and implementation insufficient for the long-term support that stable would entail. We have not announced plans to proceed further with the API. You can star http://crbug.com/112155 for updates.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to guess when a Chrome API be become stable until it does. Priorities, features, bugs, etc make it impossible to predict.